# python -m xxx script works in command line but not in .sh file?

Tags: bash, makefile

`python -m  webbrowser http://example.com/`

This script works in command line. It opens the url with default browser.

I'm creating a makefile to run some docker commands and after the containers are up, open a list of urls.

```
dev:
    docker compose up -d
    python -m  webbrowser http://localhost:8001/
    python -m  webbrowser http://localhost:8002/
    ...
```

`make dev` ends without any errors, but none of the urls opened.

Then I tried to create a .sh file to open the urls:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
python -m  webbrowser http://localhost:8001/
python -m  webbrowser http://localhost:8002/
...
```

Then make the file executable. But running it failed to open urls too.

Is it possible to open url in makefile or .sh?

Comment: How did it fail? Are you trying to execute the shell script in the same Docker container that `make dev` starts up?

Comment: Actually it's vscode's bash terminal... Running from system terminal worked... Why is that?

Comment: Again, *how* is it failing? Each line in a `make` recipe is essential a single shell script. Is it possible you just aren't waiting long enough for the Docker container to spin up the servers that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: `docker compose up -d` remove this line doesnot have any effect. By "fail", I mean the script seems to get executed, but the url is not opened in the browser, in vscode terminal. And in system terminal, the script executed and url opened in the browser.